# Specific media queries for target mobile (first), tablet & desktop

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm building a responsive layout starting with mobile (1 column) first by default and then breakpoints for tablet in landscape & portrait mode and lastly desktop.

For my tablet (1 column) breakpoints I have.

- @media (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)
- @media (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)

But for desktop, the design I'm working with has a layout (2 columns) of max width 976px only.

Is it be possible to target desktop only (min-width 976px) while preventing tablet media queries from picking them up? And on desktop if it's less than 976px it should adapt to the mobile layout.

Comment: The problem with specific sizes aimed at devices is that they may change. It's best to use [natural breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20350990/123033) as explained in the answer I gave to a similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/download/) to detect touch device. Modernizr will add `.touch` or `.no-touch` class to your html tag. So, for desktop, you will use `.touch` class to target desktop.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .touch .container { width: 960px; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert in this but I did design a website using media queries. 
 
 http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ 
 It is better to stick to the query standards given here to avoid messing up your css later on when your website takes shape.

```
@media only screen (min-device-width: 1024px)
```

This should work fine for your desktop.